# Not able to clone a in git repository

Tags: git, eclipse

I am not able clone a git repository in eclipse.
I am connected to VPN.
I get the follwoing error while cloning the git .
[image]

Comment: Hello there! Is it a private repo? Do you access to it with a ssh key / password? Can you post the error log?

Comment: This looks like a networking / permission access. Nothing git related. Contact your corporate admins.

Comment: Can you clone the repository using the command line? What error occurs?

Comment: Yes, we use companies gitlab. We create a  token through the settings menu in gitlab and use it is password

Comment: I am able to clone using git bash. I would like it to work in eclipse

Comment: it works now.. I have set the proxy for http under NetworkConnections in eclipse.